# Getting values from row in HTML table in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Main page

```
<!doctype html>
<?php 
include 'db_connect.php';    
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername']))
    header("location:main_login.php");
    ?>

<html>
<head>

<script>
   function show(){
document.getElementById("cheque").value="";
}
function hide(){
document.getElementById("cheque").value="Cash";
}
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
   {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_edit_payment.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

</script>
</head>

<body style="text-align: center">
<form name="add_payment" method="post" action="add_payment.php">
<label for="select"><span style="text-align: center">Select Client:</span></label>
  <span style="text-align: center">
  <select name="client_name" id="select" onChange="showUser(this.value)";>
   <option value="">Select:</option>
   <?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM client");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
</select>

<div id="txtHint"></div><br>

 <label for="select"><span style="text-align: center">Financial Year:</span></label>
 <select name="fy" id="fy" >
   <option value="2005-06">2005-06</option>
   <option value="2006-07">2006-07</option>
   <option value="2007-08">2007-08</option>
   <option value="2008-09">2008-09</option>
   <option value="2009-10">2009-10</option>
   <option value="2010-11">2010-11</option>
   <option value="2011-12">2011-12</option>
   <option value="2012-13">2012-13</option>
   <option value="2013-14">2013-14</option>
   <option value="2014-15">2014-15</option>
   <option value="2015-16">2015-16</option>
   <option value="2016-17">2016-17</option>
   <option value="2017-18">2017-18</option>
   <option value="2018-19">2018-19</option>
   <option value="2019-20">2019-20</option>
   <option value="2020-21">2020-21</option>
   </select>&nbsp;
   <label for="date">Date: </label>
    <input name="date" id"date" type="date">
   <label for="receiptno"><span style="text-align: right">Receipt no: </span></label>
    <input name="receiptno" type="text" id="receiptno"> &nbsp;

    <br><br>
    <label for="amount"> Amount: </label>
    <input name="amount" type="text" id="amount">
    <label for="received">Received </label>
    <input name="received" type="radio" id="received" onClick="hide();" value="Cash" checked>
    Cash &nbsp;
<input type="radio" id="received" name="received" value="Cheque" onClick="show();">Cheque
<label for="cheque">Cheque no: </label>
    <input name="cheque" value="Cash" type="text" id="cheque"><br><br>
    <label for="select">Select Auditor:</label>

  <select name="auditor_name" id="select">
  <?php 
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM auditors");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
echo "<option value=\"".$row['name']."\">".$row['name']."</option>";
}
?>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="submit" value="Add">
</form>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Its output is 
[image]

**ajax_edit_payment.php**

```
<?php

$q = $_GET['q'];
include 'db_connect.php';
$sql="SELECT name,address,mobile,email,pan,tan FROM client WHERE name = '$q'";
$sql_bill="SELECT clientname,financialyear,receiptno,amount,ddate,type,chequeno,category FROM billing WHERE clientname = '$q'";
$sql_total="SELECT SUM(amount) AS TotalAmount FROM billing";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$result_bill = mysql_query($sql_bill);
$result_total = mysql_query($sql_total);
$total= mysql_fetch_array($result_total);
echo "<h4><b>Client details</b></h4><table align='center' border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Address</th>
<th>Mobile</th>
<th>Email</th>
<th>PAN</th>
<th>VAT TIN</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {

echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['mobile'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['pan'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tan'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
echo "<h4><b>Payment received details</b></h4><table align='center' border='2'>
<tr>
<th>Client Name</th>
<th>Financial Year</th>
<th>Receipt No</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Type</th>
<th>Chequeno</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Amount</th>
</tr>";



while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_bill))
  {

echo "<tr >";
  echo "<td id=1>" . $row['clientname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=2>" . $row['financialyear'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=3>" . $row['receiptno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=4>" . $row['ddate'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=5>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=6>" . $row['chequeno'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=7>" . $row['category'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td id=8>" . $row['amount'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}
echo "<tr>";

  echo "<td colspan=7>Total</td>";
  echo "<td>".$total['TotalAmount'].  "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

?>
```

[image]
I am using AJAX to get response and final output is

Now on clicking on any row in table, I want all the  fields(financial year, receipt no,amount and so on) to be updated with the values from the row of table on which user clicks. 
Suggest me an easier way to do this

Comment: SO is for coding issues and this in itself is a whole code. I suggest you instead read tutorials like **[this](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/03/live-table-edit-with-jquery-and-ajax.html)** or **[this](http://www.infotuts.com/inline-editing-html-table-jquery-ajax-php/)** or **[this](http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/app/crud3.php)** and work your way. You can come back when you are stuck.

Comment: Ok..Let me walk through given links

Comment: You can try sending only the values of Financial year, Receipt no. etc. seperated by some special character and then split them on the front side and update the row that called the funciton.

Comment: Can I use javascript in AJAX response, i.e., in below set of code as 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result_bill))
  {
 
echo "<tr onclick=\"clicked()\">";